# FtpException when getting files

Tags: c#, ftp, passive-mode

I'm successfully establishing an ftp connection and want to get files from FTP server.

This is my code:

```
ftp.GetFile(file.Name, path + file.Name, false);
```

where ftp is FtpConnection.

And for all the other files it went well. Now, for the first time I got it and the exception msg isn't clear to me at all. Here it is:

200 Type set to I

227 Entering Passive Mode (93,186,176,75,78,64).

213 21846

What does this mean?

Comment: 213 is not an error code. Show the exception you're getting.

Comment: @CodeCaster This IS the exception I'm getting.

Comment: I do not see an exception, I see three lines of FTP log. What is the exception and what does it say? What is `FtpConnection`, it's not on MSDN, is it third-party? Then contact them on how to get useful error messages.

Comment: @CodeCaster This was in the exception message. There wasn't an inner exception and there wasn't another text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FTP is a bidirectional protocol and you need 2 connections (server <-> client)

In active mode the client connect to the server and the server connects back to the client. This is usually a problem with firewalls. In passive mode the client creates both connections, one on the ftp port, the second one on another port.

This can be for high server load or bad firewall configuration.

Comment: _"The integers list you are seeing (93,186,...) is the ports the client tried to use for the second connection. They all failed"_ - nope. (93,186,176,75,78,64) means the client must connect to 93.186.176.75:20032 (78*256+64).